# How to create VBA formulas in Germany

Tags: vba

I have a process that builds a cell with a calculation of different values

```
Val_1 = [A1]
Val_2 = [A2]
[E1] = "=-" & Val_1 & " -" & Val_2
```

This builds a formula so that the users can see how the output is calculated for example

```
E1 =-123 -234
```

I have this VBA code running correctly in UK, but when the process runs in Germany it causes an error: Anwendungs- oder objektdefinierter Fehler

I tried different things but it didn't work. For example using [E1].Formula or adding a character in from of the equal ([E1] = "^=-") and then removing it ([E1]= Right([E1], Len([E1]) - 1))

How can I make it work in Germany?

Comment: What is the host application? Excel or Access?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try concatenating with `Application.WorksheetFunction.CONCATENATE()`. In my experience, Excel functions are interpreted well between different locales.

EDIT:
Alternatively, this post should help setting up a simple if statement after determining the locale:
[VBA for Excel 2010/2013 - How to identify the system locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500552/vba-for-excel-2010-2013-how-to-identify-the-system-locale)

Answer (score 0):

Try, please:

```
   Dim Val_1 As Long, Val_2 As Long
   Val_1 = Range("A1")
   Val_2 = Range("A2")
   Range("E1").Formula = "=-" & Val_1 & " -" & Val_2
```

It will work in any installation...

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work when Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI) = 1031

Comment: @Selrac: Try also defining `Val_1` and `Val_2` in the same way. it should work. In fact, I will adapt the answer...